# android app did not work in unity3d in play mood

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I received a unity project from my friend to complete work on it in unity it's android app by unity3d so after I open the project and when I try to play the animation from the scene mode it doesn't work and this message shown in the console:
`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
character.Update () (at Assets/character.cs:64)
UnityEditor.Toolbar:OnGUI()`

and my unity version is (5.5.1f1) and my friend version is (5.5.0f3).
This is my code:

character.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class character : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
private Animator avatarAnimator;
public words passingtext;
private AndroidJavaObject VoicePlug = null;
private AndroidJavaObject activityContext = null;

void Start()
{
    avatarAnimator = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

    if (VoicePlug == null)
    {
        using (AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        {
            activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }

        using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.bas.MyProject.VoicePlug"))
        {
            if (pluginClass != null)
            {
                VoicePlug = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                VoicePlug.Call("setContext", activityContext);
                activityContext.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() => {}));
            }
        }
    }
}

Dictionary<string, int> signs = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
        {"start", 0},
        {"hello", 1},


};


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (signs.ContainsKey(passingtext.gettext()))
    {
         avatarAnimator.SetInteger("stateNum", signs[passingtext.gettext()]);

    }
    else 
    {
        //message for unstored signs
        VoicePlug.Call("showMessage", "sorry I can't understand you");
        passingtext.settext(" ");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Add code of character.cs also in your question

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: may be avatarAnimator or avatarAnimator is null

Comment: no, Its not null all the animation clips is stored in unity....

Comment: Are you certain the animator component is added to the object? Can you debug in the start() method to see if avatarAnimator  is null

Comment: may be avatarAnimator or VoicePlug is null.

Comment: yes right, voicePlug is null but how can I make sure that the avatarAnimator is null... this project was working in my friend device and we have the same codes and component...

Comment: may be you did not import some unitypackage possibly voicePlug unitypackage  or the game folder was not copied completely

Comment: maybe because the unity version that I use is different than my friend?

Comment: which packages should I import?

Comment: i think you should build and test it in android may be voicePlug is for android.You need to ask your friend about this.VoicePlug han no complie error so i think it has already been imported,just ask you friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your game in Android device.You have a code that is for android only.See: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

To make sure there is no error in editor so that you can test you app in editor for development. use

if (!Application.isEditor)

Application.isEditor will be true when running in Unity and false if your game is running in android or other platform.

Edit you code as shown below

```
    public class character : MonoBehaviour {

   // Use this for initialization
    private Animator avatarAnimator;
    public words passingtext;
    private AndroidJavaObject VoicePlug = null;
    private AndroidJavaObject activityContext = null;

    void Start()
    {
        avatarAnimator = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
        if (!Application.isEditor)
        {
            if (VoicePlug == null)
            {
                using (AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
                {
                    activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
                }

                using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.bas.MyProject.VoicePlug"))
                {
                    if (pluginClass != null)
                    {
                        VoicePlug = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                        VoicePlug.Call("setContext", activityContext);
                        activityContext.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() => { }));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, int> signs = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
        {"start", 0},
        {"hello", 1},


};


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (signs.ContainsKey(passingtext.gettext()))
        {
            avatarAnimator.SetInteger("stateNum", signs[passingtext.gettext()]);

        }
       else
       {
           // message for unstored signs
           if (!Application.isEditor) { 
            VoicePlug.Call("showMessage", "sorry I can't understand you");
           }
            passingtext.settext(" ");
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: it's work in the android emulator but I want this app work in unity because when trying the app on the android device I had a problem with the keyboard language in how to convert it from English to Arabic to input text and try the animation character.

Comment: @Louisa VoicePlug will only work in android and you can not test it in unity for example I was working with google play service which is for android(can not be used by other platform like desktop,xbox) so i always have to run it in android to test it(but we can use (if Application.isEditor) to fake login in unity so we can test the game in unity without using google play login in unity). Application.isEditor will be true if you run it in unity and false in android.

Comment: @Louisa if it work in emulator then in your android device you have to change android language setting. Also can you tell me what VoicePlug exactly do?

Comment: in my app the user will be allowed to enter text via text field that I did it in unity and also allowed to enter voice via google recognize speech which I used the voicePlug for it but it doesn't matter if it does not work now, what exactly I want to test it and let it play in Unity is the text field and the animation, I  want to enter text then the animation will play the character

Comment: @Louisa did you try my answer ? What error did you got ?

Comment: @Louisa if the answer worked then you can accept the answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers